# Can't turn up ethernet link

Tags: ubuntu

My wireline Internet suddenly stopped working on Ubuntu 16.04. I did "ip link show" and noticed some states are DOWN:

```
ip link show
1: lo : <LOOPBACK, UP, LOWER_UP> ... state UNKNOWN ...
2: enp1s0f0: <NO-CARRIER, BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP> ... state DOWN ...
3: enp1s0f1: <NO-CARRIER, BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP> ... state DOWN ..
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER, BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP> ... state DOWN ...
```

[Note: since I can't use Internet on that machine, so just type in part of the command output, not full command output]

I think I need to turn on enp1s0f0, so I did this:

```
ifconfig enp1s0f0 up
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
```

What's the problem in this operation?

Comment: beside having to run most commands as root user for them to work, you have a `NO-CARRIER` state: that means there is a physical problem between the network interface and where it is connected to. This won't be solved by a command but by checking if you don't have a physical/hardware problem.

Comment: It also could have simply died.

Comment: Put `sudo` in front of the command. But I would expect that NO-CARRIER means the cable got unplugged. Check it, both ends, and the router end too. Especially if the little plastic clip is broken, the cable might have moved just far enough to become disconnected.